# How to click a link in Selenium using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have some links that are not buttons, each row of the table result has one link called View :

```
<a class="view-link" aria-label="View" href="/applicant_submissions/8">
                <i aria-hidden="true" title="View" class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open icon-spacing"></i>
```

Can you please show me how to use Selenium using Ruby to click on this link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
driver.find_element(:class, "view-link").click
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to click the first or second or any nth link ? Thanks,

Comment: @akram, if you have several links with the same class name -- you should use lists and find_elements-method. After that get the appropriate link by using the index in the list.

Comment: did you mean :    driver.find_element(:class, "view-link")[0].click

Comment: @akram, yes, but you should use find_elements-method for that.

Comment: Thanks, it's working, I have another question, for the login script I am hard coding the username and password, is there any way to read them from a file instead ? Thanks.

Comment: @akram, this is offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby so, please, find my solution in Python.

You can use these locators:

Using class name:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('view-link').click
```

Or

Using XPath:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href="/applicant_submissions/8']").click
```